# Ruby - Loop will not break

Tags: ruby, loops, break

I have written this code in Ruby for something for The Odin Project (Tic Tac Toe) and it won't break when @won is true. I can confirm that @won is becoming true but it won't break. The full code is at http://pastebin.com/GNJYC0hc

```
b = Board.init
b.create_squares
b.display_board
loop do
  if @turn == "player"
    print "Your turn! "
    b.player_turn
    b.display_board
    b.check_for_win
    @turn = "computer"
  else
    sleep 1.2
    b.computer_turn
    b.display_board
    b.check_for_win
    @turn = "player"
  end
  break if @won
end
```

**FIXED** I changed the code to use 1 instance of Board and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Did you check the value of `@won` to see if it's being set properly? Before your break, put `puts @won.inspect?` or something similar to see what it looks like. If you're loop's not breaking, that says that `@won` is either not getting set, or is always set to `false`.

Comment: @lurker: Actually I did set '@won' but in a different part of the code.  I'm adding it to the top now. http://pastebin.com/GNJYC0hc

Comment: maybe it should be `break if b.won`?

Comment: Not an answer, but why not say `until @won do` rather than `loop do`?   `break` here is just a half-assed replacement for having a conditional in the loop.

Comment: Presumably, `check_for_win()` sets `@won` to `true` or `false`.  Since you do not show us that method, how do you expect us to help?

Comment: @lurker You can check the code. It should be in the win function, but it isn't.

Comment: OK, then how did you confirm that the value of `@won` is `true`?

Comment: @lurker It seems that changing it to use 1 instance of Board worked. The code should be working better now and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you've learned the pitfalls of presenting incomplete code in an SO question. I suggest you post your corrected code (all of it) on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby), a sister site whose purpose is to help posters improve working code. You would learn a lot by doing so.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. In addition to lesson learned @CarySwoveland indicates, usually when something that should obviously work (like `break if @won`) doesn't work, it's very unlikely (albeit possible) that the language is broken (your statement that the loop doesn't break *even though @won is `true`* wasn't really true, since `@won` wasn't really `true` in this context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is rather weird. You are creating 2 board objects - you calling `.play` on first instance, then create another one inside `play` method and all game logic is performed on second instance. So you should do `break if b.won`.

But better refactor your code so .play is not creating new instances.

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but I used to be using .play as a class method and it didn't work. thinking about how to fix that

Comment: @meecoder: A class method isn't going to see instance variables -- or rather, the instance variables it does see will be those of `Board` (the instance of `Class`), not *a* `Board`.

Comment: @cHao Thanks! I figured this out and reworked the code and it's working now.